# Control Firefox Download Prompt Using Selenium and Python

Tags: python

Here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/home/ripundeep/Desktop/Python Challenges /")    
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/csv")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv")
profile.update_preferences()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#id").send_keys("keyword")
WebDriverWait(driver, 1, poll_frequency=0.1).until(lambda drv:  len(drv.find_elements_by_css_selector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit")) > 0)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#submitid").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#DownloadLinkId").click()
```

I want to stop firefox to show me download prompt and save it automatically and I have tried all possible solutions but didn't work. Please help.

Comment: Can you post some of the *...all possible solutions*?

Comment: 1st solution is in code.... by changing profile of firefox using selenium.
2nd solution, I have checked "Don't ask me again" when it prompted and then re-run the code but same position occur.
3rd solution is go through the changes I can make in firefox preferences or other settings manually.
But eventually nothing didn't work. As I run the code prompt ocuur.

Answer (score 4):

I remember providing more mime-type variants usually helped to solve issues like this:

```
mime_types = [
    'text/plain', 
    'application/vnd.ms-excel', 
    'text/csv', 
    'application/csv', 
    'text/comma-separated-values', 
    'application/download', 
    'application/octet-stream', 
    'binary/octet-stream', 
    'application/binary', 
    'application/x-unknown'
]
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", ",".join(mime_types))
```

I also think you should not be calling `profile.update_preferences()`.

---

Aside from that, here are the steps to see what mime-type Firefox detects:

- manually download the file with Firefox checking the "automatically save this file type" checkbox
- open Help -> Troubleshooting Information
- locate the "Profile Folder" button, click it
- inside the profile folder locate the `mimeTypes.rdf` file
- open the file in a text editor and look for the mimetypes mentioned there - the XML node attribute values that start with `urn:mimetype`
- use the mimetypes you found in the `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` comma-separated value

Comment: @user3805995 updated with instructions on how to see what mime-type firefox thinks this file is of. Hope that helps.

Comment: FYI, `mimeTypes.rdf` may not exist anymore.  `handlers.json` is a possible place to look

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly have this **firefox profile**, if you are using **Python** then you could this :

```
profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/msword, application/csv, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream");
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True);
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False);
profile.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Users\\***\\****\\Desktop\\Automation")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile, executable_path = "Full file path to gecko driver.exe")
```