# How to overcome Firefox prompt to save file

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

been trying to get python selenium to save an excel file (.xlsx) via the Firefox browser.
My automation routine has been disrupted by a prompt to save or open the file that Firefox is accessing. I tried searching for workarounds and solutions online and none of those solutions worked. I've tried this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/42hg1c/selenium_download_wont_automatically_save_without/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=&utm_content=post_body), didn't work, this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458811/control-firefox-download-prompt-using-selenium-and-python) and this [other stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907319/download-file-with-firefox-bypassing-popup-selenium-python/52911310) did not help as well.

My current code is as such:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Starting Firefox
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 1) # 0 means to download to the desktop, 1 means to download to the default "Downloads" directory, 2 means to use the directory
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
mime_types = [
    'text/plain',
    'attachment/vnd.ms-excel',
    'text/csv',
    'application/csv',
    'text/comma-separated-values',
    'application/download',
    'application/octet-stream',
    'binary/octet-stream',
    'application/binary',
    'application/x-unknown',
    'application/excel',
    'attachment/csv',
    'attachment/excel'
]
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", ",".join(mime_types))
fp.set_preference("browser.preferences.instantApply",True)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp, firefox_binary=None, timeout=30, capabilities=None, proxy=None, executable_path='/Users/cadellteng/Downloads/geckodriver', options=None, firefox_options=None, service_args=None, desired_capabilities=None, log_path=None, keep_alive=True)
browser.get('https://sg.quickHR.co')
```

I would really appreciate it if someone has a working code to show me or tell me what I'm doing wrong over here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in mime types. You can get mime type in **Network** tab - **Response Headers** `content-type`.

Try with below:

```
mime_types = [
    'text/plain',
    'attachment/vnd.ms-excel',
    'text/csv',
    'application/csv',
    'text/comma-separated-values',
    'application/download',
    'application/octet-stream',
    'binary/octet-stream',
    'application/binary',
    'application/x-unknown',
    'application/excel',
    'attachment/csv',
    'attachment/excel'
    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'application/msexcel',
    'application/x-msexcel',
    'application/x-ms-excel',
    'application/x-excel',
    'application/x-dos_ms_excel',
    'application/xls',
    'application/x-xls',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
]
```

Comment: Wow! It worked! THANK YOU SO MUCH!
Which of the above mime is for excel to be saved and bypassing the prompt?
Unfortunately, I couldn't find the network tab you mentioned.

Wish I could upvote your answer a thousand times.

Comment: All mime types for excel with `excel`. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148497/in-chrome-whats-the-simplest-way-to-view-the-mime-type-of-a-document) how to get it from chrome, almost sampe for firefox and ie.